# Close InputStream wrapped into IO

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

I'm using `IO` (`cats`/`scalaz` does not matter). And I want to use bracket to close `InputStream` after I'm done with it. The problem is that I'm reading gzipped files. Here is what I tried:

***I*** (Incorrect).

```
val io1 = IO(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/tmp/file")))
val io2 = io1.map(is => new GZIPInputStream(is))
val io3 = io2.bracket{_ =>
  IO(println("use"))
  //empty usage
}{ is =>
  println("close")
  IO(is.close())
}
```

This is incorrect because of if `/tmp/file` is a broken zip-file with invalid magic we will never reach "resource release" bracket.

***II*** (Incorrect).

```
val io1 = IO(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/tmp/file")))
val io3 = io1.bracket{is =>
  val gzis = new GZIPInputStream(is)
  IO(println("use"))
  //empty usage
}{ is =>
  println("close")
  IO(is.close())
}
```

This is incorrect because we are closing the underlying stream, but not the `GzipInputStream` so we may end up losing some buffered data inside.

In java I could simply do this without flushing:

```
var is: InputStream = null
try{
  is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/tmp/file"))
  is = new GZIPInputStream(is)
  //use
} finally {
  if(is ne null)
    is.close()
}
```

Can you suggest some approach for dealing with `GzipInputStream`?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem to call `close` on input stream several times, so you can close InputStream and GZIPInputStream separatelly.

In Java it is common to let `try with resources` hanlde both streams

```
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/tmp/file"));
     GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(is)){
  //use gzis
}
// both streams are closed in implicit finaly clause
```

You can translate this approach to IO brackets

```
val io1 = IO(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/tmp/file")))
val io2 = io1.bracket { is =>
  IO(new GZIPInputStream(is)).bracket { gzis =>
    IO(println("using gzis"))
  }(gzis => IO(gzis.close()))
}(is => IO(is.close()))
```

To awoid nested brackets you can use [Resource](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/resource.html)

```
def openFile(path: Path) = Resource(IO {
  val is = Files.newInputStream(path)
  (is, IO(is.close()))
})

def openGZIP(is: InputStream) = Resource(IO {
  val gzis = new GZIPInputStream(is)
  (gzis, IO(gzis.close()))
})

val gzip: Resource[IO, GZIPInputStream] = for {
  is <- openFile(Paths.get("/tmp/file"))
  gzis <- openGZIP(is)
} yield gzis

gzip.use {
  gzis => IO(println("using gzis"))
}
```